# Stretch the video to the entire browser

Tags: c#, html, winforms, webbrowser-control

Please help me stretch the video to the full web browser in Windows Forms.
The code I use:

```
web_browser.DocumentText = String.Format("<html><head>" +
  "<meta http-equiv=\"X-UA-Compatible\" content=\"IE=Edge\"/>" +
  "</head><body>" +
  "<iframe width=\"100%\" height=\"218\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/{0}\"" +
  "frameborder = \"0\" allow = \"autoplay; encrypted-media\" allowfullscreen></iframe>" +
  "</body></html>", VideoID);
```

[image]

Comment: Are the white strips part of the video itself?

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't make sense? I'm assuming this is a youtube video?

You can grab the embed link from any youtube video like
`<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/BsyJMy8_lO0" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

and embed that with jsx or html? Then change the width and height properties

Comment: I asked a specific question, I need to remove these white stripes, I simply do not want to see them, can you help me with this?I asked a specific question, I need to remove these white stripes, I simply do not want to see them, can you help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

You can set an in-line style inside the `HEAD` block with `<style type="text/css">`, affecting the `body` and `html` elements `size`, `margin` and `padding` while setting the IFrame `width` and `height` to `100%` as attributes of the `<iframe>` element itself.

The video size is proportional. If you need to constraint the video to a specific size, you can always set the **`WebBrowser.MaximumSize`** property (or the same property of its container Form, if the WebBrowser is anchored/docked).

Note that I have used an interpolated string, but it's of course the same using `string.Format()`.

```
string videoID = "Some ID";

webBrowser1.Navigate("");
var doc = webBrowser1.Document.OpenNew(true);
doc.Write(
    "<html><head><meta http-equiv=\"X-UA-Compatible\" content=\"IE=Edge\"/> " +
    "<style type=\"text/css\"> " +
    "body { background: black; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; }" +
    "iframe { margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; display: block; }" +
    "</style></head><body> " +
    $"<iframe width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/{videoID} \"" +
    "allow = \"autoplay; encrypted-media\" allowfullscreen></iframe>" +
    "</body></html>");

webBrowser1.Refresh();
```

`background: black;` is irrelevant. Just the usual background color of Video players.

**Activation of the WebBrowser advanced compatibility mode and GPU rendering support**

Add the **`WebBrowserAdvancedFeatures`** class to the Project and insert this function call in the Form's constructor, the features need to be activated before the WebBrowser is initialized.
In `Form.OnFormClosing`, the advanced features are disable.

```
using System.Security.AccessControl;
using Microsoft.Win32;

public SomeForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    WebBrowserAdvancedFeatures.ActivateWBAdvancedFeatures(Path.GetFileName(Application.ExecutablePath));
}

protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    WebBrowserAdvancedFeatures.DeactivateWBAdvancedFeatures(Path.GetFileName(Application.ExecutablePath));
    base.OnFormClosing(e);
}

// (...)

class WebBrowserAdvancedFeatures
{
    private static string baseKeyName = @"Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl";
    private static string featuresKey = baseKeyName+ @"\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION";
    private static string hardwareAccelKey = baseKeyName + @"\FEATURE_GPU_RENDERING";

    public static void ActivateWBAdvancedFeatures(string executableName)
    {
        RegistryKey wbFeatureKey = null;
        RegistryKey wbGpuKey = null;
        try {
            wbFeatureKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(featuresKey,
            RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree, RegistryRights.WriteKey);

            if (wbFeatureKey == null) {
                wbFeatureKey = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(featuresKey, true);
            }
            wbFeatureKey.SetValue(executableName, 11001, RegistryValueKind.DWord);

            wbGpuKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(hardwareAccelKey,
                RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree, RegistryRights.WriteKey);

            if (wbGpuKey == null) {
                wbGpuKey = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(hardwareAccelKey, true);
            }
            wbGpuKey.SetValue(executableName, 11001, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
        }
        finally {
            wbFeatureKey?.Dispose();
            wbGpuKey?.Dispose();
        }
    }
    public static void DeactivateWBAdvancedFeatures(string executableName)
    {
        using (var wbFeatureKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(featuresKey,
            RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree, RegistryRights.WriteKey)) {
            wbFeatureKey.DeleteValue(executableName, false);
        }

        using (var wbAccelKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(hardwareAccelKey,
            RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree, RegistryRights.WriteKey)) {
            wbAccelKey.DeleteValue(executableName, false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: After I used your solution, it got even worse.https://imgur.com/WFWoUBd

Comment: I have made an edit that should make it more *compatible* (copy everything over, don't make changes to existing code). Also, have you enabled the [advanced features](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38514446/7444103)?

Comment: [See the result I have](https://imgur.com/rYOTp3R) with these settings.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/drfhUcZ                                                                                     
 I don't understand how you got this result, but here's my

Comment: You didn't correct the code with what I posted here. Also, have you enabled the advanced features, as described in my previous comment? Anyway, first update the code, what you're using now won't work.

Comment: Edited the code, and now a new problem. It is not possible to open the video in full screen, as well as black bars, which it would be desirable to get rid of https://imgur.com/a/QiRKVo5

Comment: Well, that's a completely different story. You cannot click on the overlay button and maximize your Form, that's another type container, unrelated with the WebBrowser. I've posted something like that for GeckoFx [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54508658/7444103). If you cannot make it work (you have to handle the HtmlDocument events yourself), post back. I'll see whether I can make it work with the standard WebBrowser. It appears, however, that the main problem is fixed now. I'll also post the implementation to set the advanced feature.

Comment: complains about the code:             using (var wbAccelKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(hardwareAccelKey,
                RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree, RegistryRights.WriteKey))
            {
                wbAccelKey.SetValue(executableName, 1, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
            }

Comment: See that your app is not set to `Prefer 32-bit` in `Project->Properties->Build`

Comment: System.NullReferenceException: "An object reference does not indicate an instance of an object."

Comment: Yes, well, what object is null? Did you read the previous comment? If you have an error of sort, you have to paste the text of the exception. Btw, that code works without any problem if you have set it up correctly and used it as it is. If something doesn't still work when you have followed the instructions, update your question with the code you're using now.

Comment: Have you checked whether you app is set to to 32bit, as described? Have you registered the application executable, as shown in the second part of the code (all parts are needed)?

Comment: Yes, I unchecked it, made a separate class for your code, and added it to the main form.

Comment: So, it was 32bit. Now, all you have to do is to remove any changes you have made and copy/paste the code I posted here exactly as it is inside the Form that uses the WebBrowser control. Add the `WebBrowserAdvancedFeatures.ActivateWBAdvancedFeatures(...)` in the Form constructor, right after `InitializeComponent()`. The rest, you can just paste it in somewhere (inside the Form's code file). If you have exceptions, post the exceptions text. Update your question, showing what you have done.

Comment: Your code just doesn't work, I don't understand what I should do with it?

Comment: https://yadi.sk/d/shcfkYOrOMGt2Q Here is a test project that I did, but even there what you did doesn't work. Inside is a screenshot of the error

Comment: I posted the project so you can see what I'm doing wrong, please help me