# C# WebBrowser problem with Cloudflare webiste

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control, cloudflare

I'm trying to navigate my WebBrowser inside my Windows Form Application to a website that uses Cloudflare.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
webBrowser1.Navigate("WEBSITE URL");
```

But when the webBrowser1 navigates to the site it get stuck on this site from Cloudflare and does not redirect to the website

```
Checking your browser before accessing www.WEBSITE.COM
This process is automatic. Your browser will redirect to your requested content shortly.
```

Is there a way to stop the webBrowser1 from getting stuck here?

Comment: Have you set the emulation mode to IE11? Or maybe start using WebView2, if possible.

Comment: No i dont know how to do it :/

Comment: Take the `WebBrowserAdvancedFeatures` class from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59859511/7444103) and call its `ActivateWBAdvancedFeatures()` method, as described there, before you create any instance of the WebBrowser control (I assume you have already disabled scripting errors notifications). -- Or as mentioned, get WebView2: [Getting started with WebView2 in Windows Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/gettingstarted/winforms)

Comment: `WebBrowser` (MSIE 11) is obsolete and isn't compartible with Internet.